# How to find the object in an array where particular object value is max

Tags: json, angular, angular6, angular5

Hi Below is the JSON array of ojects

```
[
  {
    "BookingId": 366024,
    "BookingDetailId": 340708,
    "JobCode" : 13
  },
  {
    "BookingId": 366023,
    "BookingDetailId": 340707,
    "JobCode" : 12
  },
  {
    "BookingId": 366022,
    "BookingDetailId": 340706,
    "JobCode" : 12
   }
]
```

I want to get particular array object where BookingId is Max where JobCode is 12, for eg. In above array I want object {
    "BookingId": 366023,
    "BookingDetailId": 340707,
    "JobCode" : 12
  } whose BookingId is max and JobCode is 12.

How to do it in angular 6

tried code

```
var a = this.GridSource.find(x => x.JobCode == 12 && 
x.BookingId == Math.max.apply(Math, this.GridSource.map
(function(o) { return o.BookingId; })));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use reduce for this. I did an example below, hope this helps. If were are no items that meet conditions, then result of reduce will be *null*

Also, don't forget about the types :)

```
interface GridItem {
  BookingId: number;
  BookingDetailId: number;
  JobCode: number;
}

const GridSource: GridItem[] = [
  {
    BookingId: 366024,
    BookingDetailId: 340708,
    JobCode: 13
  },
  {
    BookingId: 366023,
    BookingDetailId: 340707,
    JobCode: 12
  },
  {
    BookingId: 366022,
    BookingDetailId: 340706,
    JobCode: 12
  }
];

const foundGridItem: GridItem = GridSource.reduce(
  (result: GridItem, value: GridItem) =>
    value.JobCode === 12 &&
    (result === null || value.BookingId > result.BookingId)
      ? value
      : result,
  null
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of reduce to find the max element and then using it in find.

```
var max = array.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
    return prev['BookingId'] > curr['BookingId'] ? prev : curr;
});

var elem = array.find(x => x['JobCode'] == 12 && x['BookingId'] == max['BookingId']);
```